# Vanilla Javascript - How to loop through just elements in the DOM using querySelectorAll('*')

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, addeventlistener

```js
var cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".btn--cancel");
var acceptBtn = document.querySelector(".btn--accept");

var thankYouPopup = document.querySelector(".thank-you-popup");
var comeBackSoonPopup = document.querySelector(".come-back-soon-popup");

document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    if (
      ((e.target.className !== "btn btn--cancel" ||
          e.target.className !== "btn btn--accept") &&
        e.target.className == "btn-container") ||
      (e.target.className !== "thank-you-popup" &&
        e.target.className == "thank-you-container") ||
      (e.target.className !== "come-back-soon-popup" &&
        e.target.className == "come-back-soon-container")
    ) {
      console.log("foo");
      var els = document.querySelectorAll("*");

      for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        console.log("els[i]", els[i]);
        if (
          els[i].left === "0" &&
          (els[i].className === "thank-you-popup" ||
            els[i].className === "come-back-soon-popup")
        ) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            els[i].style.left = "10000px";
          }, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  false
);

function myEventHandler(el) {
  if (getComputedStyle(el).left == "10000px") {
    el.style.left = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.left = "10000px";
    }, 8000);
  } else {
    el.style.left = "10000px";
  }
}

cancelBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    myEventHandler(comeBackSoonPopup);
  },
  false
);

cancelBtn.removeEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    myEventHandler(comeBackSoonPopup);
  },
  false
);

acceptBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    myEventHandler(thankYouPopup);
  },
  false
);

acceptBtn.removeEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    myEventHandler(thankYouPopup);
  },
  false
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0%;
  font: 1rem system-ui;
}

.thank-you-container,
.come-back-soon-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.thank-you-popup,
.come-back-soon-popup {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 38px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 3px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10000px;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

p {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.btn-container {
  margin: 5% 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.225s ease-in;
  transition: background-color 0.225s ease-in;
}

.btn--cancel {
  background-color: #ff4136;
}

.btn--cancel:hover {
  background-color: #e2392f;
}

.btn--accept {
  background: #01ff70;
}

.btn--accept:hover {
  background-color: #06da63;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="thank-you-container">
    <div class="thank-you-popup">
      <p>Thank you!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn btn--cancel">cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn--accept">accept</button>
  </div>

  <div class="come-back-soon-container">
    <div class="come-back-soon-popup">
      <p>Come back soon!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<!--

In this exercise, you are asked to create a couple of buttons that, when clicked, trigger the display of popups. We want to not only see your coding skills, but also your eye for design and experience. Follow the instructions below and feel free to explain what you're doing or ask questions as you go.

1. Create two buttons centered on the page, next to each other. One should be for canceling and the other for accepting, so use appropriate background colors. The buttons should have rounded borders and should brighten up a bit with easing on hover.

2. Create two popups, one positioned a bit off from the bottom right corner of the page and the other from the top right. The popups should have rounded corners, a slightly thick border, and some padding. One popup should contain the text "Thank you!" while the other should contain the text "Come back soon."

3. Now, position the two popups off screen to the right using CSS.

4. We will now complete the exercise. Add a click handler to each button. For the first button, when clicked we want to slide the "Come back soon" popup from the right into view. For the second button, when clicked we want to slide the "Thank you!" popup from the right into view. The popups should slide back out of view 8 seconds after coming into view or when clicking anywhere on the page except the buttons and the popups.

5. BONUS: Make this work for touch devices!

-->
```

I'm close to fulfilling this requirement in an exercise:

> We will now complete the exercise. Add a click handler to each button.
> For the first button, when clicked we want to slide the "Come back
> soon" popup from the right into view. For the second button, when
> clicked we want to slide the "Thank you!" popup from the right into
> view. The popups should slide back out of view 8 seconds after coming
> into view or when clicking anywhere on the page except the buttons and
> the popups.

I decided to isolate this eventListener on the document to loop only elements in the DOM but when I `console.log` it's spitting out every possible *node* i.e. blank spaces, css, script tags.

Can anyone help me just isolate the elements in the dom?

I have included a working example, HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " it's spitting out every possible node i.e. blank spaces, css, script tags." — Script elements are elements and it does only spit out elements (the representation of an element includes its descendants of course).

Comment: script tags, style tags etc are all nodes - you would not get "blank spaces" though

Comment: Sorry I guess I un-elegantly asked how to just get the DOM elements between the body tags which aren’t white spaces. Just html tags.

Comment: so that would be the answer below -i.e. `document.body.querySelectorAll('*')`

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
```